# What Cellbase resources are 0-indexed, and which are 1-indexed?

Tags: genome, genomics, interval, genomicranges

The UCSC Genome Browser Team is [clear](http://genome.ucsc.edu/blog/the-ucsc-genome-browser-coordinate-counting-systems/) about that the genome browser GUI indexing which is 1-based, closed interval. Genomic sequence retrieval via the UCSC REST API is 1-based, closed interval. All UCSC tables are indexed at 0-based, half-open intervals.

However, I can't seem to find a list of how resources are indexed at [Cellbase](http://bioinfo.hpc.cam.ac.uk/cellbase/webservices/). I know genomic sequence queries are 1-based and closed-interval, but are all the other tables? I could come up with tests for each resource I use at Cellbase, but I'd need a known true value for each test, which is impossible or impractical for most resources I need.

It's such a fundamental thing to know that there's probably a description somewhere, but I can't seem to find it. Or maybe there is a method to easily know, but I don't know that method. I've looked at:

- the Cellbase [website](http://bioinfo.hpc.cam.ac.uk/cellbase/webservices/),
- the Cellbase [wiki](http://docs.bioinfo.cipf.es/projects/cellbase/wiki) (down for maintenance as of 3/11/20), and
- I've read both the original [NAR paper](https://academic.oup.com/nar/article/40/W1/W609/1752209) and
- the recent [BMC Bioinformatics](https://bmcbioinformatics.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/s12859-019-2726-4) paper on the pycellbase library (which I'm super-excited to try).

There is no mention of how nucleotides are counted. I'm sure I'm missing something; any help would be appreciated.